# How to get only QR Code as a image after scanning QR code from scanner result

Tags: java, android

I am trying to get QR code as a image from scanning QR Code result I need that image to place in image view am using ZXingScanner for scanning QR Code

I am not getting exact QR Code image from result am also getting extra part of image

```
 @Override
   public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        if (mResultHandler == null) {
            return;
        }

    try {
        Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
        Camera.Size size = parameters.getPreviewSize();
        int width = size.width;
        int height = size.height;

        if (DisplayUtils.getScreenOrientation(getContext()) == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
            int rotationCount = getRotationCount();
            if (rotationCount == 1 || rotationCount == 3) {
                int tmp = width;
                width = height;
                height = tmp;
            }
            data = getRotatedData(data, camera);
        }

        Result rawResult = null;
        PlanarYUVLuminanceSource source = buildLuminanceSource(data, width, height);
```

After scanning I will get result from scanner I need to decode qr code from that result with same width and height

```
Bitmap bitmapqr = renderGrayScaleBitmap(source);

 if (source != null) {
            BinaryBitmap bitmap = new BinaryBitmap(new HybridBinarizer(source));
            try {
                rawResult = mMultiFormatReader.decodeWithState(bitmap);
            } catch (ReaderException re) {
                // continue
            } catch (NullPointerException npe) {
                // This is terrible
            } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException aoe) {

            } finally {
                mMultiFormatReader.reset();
            }

            if (rawResult == null) {
                LuminanceSource invertedSource = source.invert();
                bitmap = new BinaryBitmap(new HybridBinarizer(invertedSource));
                try {
                    rawResult = mMultiFormatReader.decodeWithState(bitmap);
                } catch (NotFoundException e) {
                    // continue
                } finally {
                    mMultiFormatReader.reset();
                }
            }
        }

        final Result finalRawResult = rawResult;

        if (finalRawResult != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onPreviewFrame: "+ finalRawResult);
            Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // Stopping the preview can take a little long.
                    // So we want to set result handler to null to discard subsequent calls to
                    // onPreviewFrame.
                    ResultHandler tmpResultHandler = mResultHandler;
                    mResultHandler = null;

                    stopCameraPreview();
                    if (tmpResultHandler != null) {
                        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                tmpResultHandler.handleResult(finalRawResult);
                            }
                        },1800);
                        tmpResultHandler.handleQRImageAnimation(bitmapqr);

                    }
                }
            });
        } else {
            camera.setOneShotPreviewCallback(this);
        }
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, e.toString(), e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

this function which is am using for decoding the qr code from result which we get when we scanned the QR Code

```
@NotNull
private Bitmap renderGrayScaleBitmap(@NotNull PlanarYUVLuminanceSource source) {
    int[] pixels = source.renderThumbnail();
    int width = source.getThumbnailWidth();
    int height = source.getThumbnailHeight();
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(pixels, 0, width, width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, out);
    return bitmap;
}
```

Comment: So, where are you exactly stuck or... what are failing?

Comment: i am unable to get exact qr code view

Comment: Did you achieve something? an image or something? does the code you have work?

Comment: What exactly does or doesn't work? Do you get compiler errors? Runtime errors? Is the actual result different from your expected result?

Comment: actually am getting one bitmap image but not exactly QR code part it is giving other image part also that's the issue @BogdanAndroid